# how to crawl webpages base on the info on the index page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to write a spider to crawl certain pages base on the data or info on the index page. And then store the result in a database.

For example, let say I would like to crawl stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy
I would go through the index page, if the question is not in my database, then I would store the answer count in the database, then follow the link of the question and crawl that page.

if the question is already in the database, but the number of answer is greater than the one in the database: crawl that page again.

if the question is already in the database and the answer counter is the same: skip this question.

At the moment I could get all the links and answer counts(in this example)on the index page.
but I don't know how to make the spider to follow the link to the question page base on the answer count.

Is there a way to do this with one spider instead of having two spiders, one spider is getting all the links on the index page, compares the data with the database, exports a json or csv file, and then passes it to another spider to crawl the question page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use BaseSpider. That way you can make all the logic depend on the content you are scraping. I personally prefer BaseSpider since it gives you a lot more control over the scraping process.

The spider should look something like this (this is more of a pseudo code):

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from myproject.items import MyItem

class StackOverflow(BaseSpider):
    name = 'stackoverflow.com'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        for question in hxs.select('//question-xpath'):
            question_url = question.select('./question-url')
            answer_count = question.select('./answer-count-xpath')
            # you'll have to write the xpaths and db logic yourself
            if get_db_answer_count(question_url) != answer_count[0]:
                yield Request(question_url, callback = self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        insert_question_and_answers_into_db
        pass
```

Comment: Can I add URLs in the start_urls list dynamically when the spider is running? In your example, the spider starts scraping the first question page, but it doesn't carry on to the second page. Can I add second page to the start_urls base on what I scraped on the first page? For example, if the last question of the first page is not in my database, which means there might be more new questions on the second page which I haven't scraped. So I should go to the second page and check. Can I somehow append the new url to the start_urls while the spider is running?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [CrawlSpider](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider) and the Rules do (be sure to check out the example). You could first get the information from the index site (though your approach counting answers is somehow flawed: what if a user deleted a post and a new one has been added) and decide on each sub page, if you want to get its information or not.

Put simple: use the spider on the index pages and follow its questions. When given a question, check if you want to get the information or [drop/ignore the question](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html).

Comment: Thanks. Counting the number of answer is just an example. But I'd like to store the answer count(in this example) alongside the scraped data in the database as well. My problem with using Rules is that it only checks the link pattern. I am trying to build a spider that would follow the link base on certain data on the index page. To continue my stackoverflow example, if the question is asked by user1499532, then follow then link, else: drop/ignore.

Comment: This can't be done with rules but with other techniques by Scrapy. You could create a pipeline that recieves a site (answer) and decides if it will process it. Another way would be to check it before creating an item. THe spider iteself is not able to decide this, but one of the mechanisms available to it.